# Reactjs form not working keeps on resetting values on eventChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I'm trying to make a very simple BMI calculator in react as part of a first project.  I wrote it so that it takes 3 inputs, 2 text and a submit button that when clicked will make an alert to the user with their BMI.  The code itself works, but as soon as you edit any of the inputs then the height input turns into 0 and won't allow you to edit it while the first input mass works normally.  I think this is a problem with handling change for that event.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

class BMI_div extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {mass: 67.0,
     height: 1.8
   };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({mass: event.target.mass});
    this.setState({height: event.target.height});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    const mass = this.state.mass;
    const height = this.state.height;
    const bmi = Math.round(mass/(height*height));
    let msg;
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
      msg = "Underweight";
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
      msg = "BMI is Normal";
    } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9) {
      msg = "Overweight";
    } else if (bmi >= 30) {
      msg = "Obesity";
    } else {
      msg = "Oof something broke";
    }
    alert('Your BMI is: ' + bmi + '\n' + msg);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Mass (kg):
          <input type="text" value={this.state.mass} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Height (m):
          <input type="text" value={this.state.height} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <BMI_div />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 2 things. First, put a `name="..."` attribute on both inputs. Next, you have to handle changing state in `handleChange` correctly.

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="mass" value={this.state.mass} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input type="text" name="height" value={this.state.height} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

With the above code changes, you're in business. Here's why this works...

When you name an input within a `<form>`, that input will be accessible by its name from the event object - `event.target.<input name>.value`. Since you're using the same event handler for both inputs, I've used JavaScript to dynamically set the *key* in the state as well as its value. You should never call `setState` back to back like you had it. A single call is suffice with whatever information you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.target.value` when you want to get the value of an input field.  I like to use the name field of the input to define which state value will get updated.

```js
class BMI_div extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mass: 67.0,
      height: 1.8
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const mass = this.state.mass;
    const height = this.state.height;
    const bmi = Math.round(mass / (height * height));
    let msg;
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
      msg = "Underweight";
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
      msg = "BMI is Normal";
    } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9) {
      msg = "Overweight";
    } else if (bmi >= 30) {
      msg = "Obesity";
    } else {
      msg = "Oof something broke";
    }
    alert('Your BMI is: ' + bmi + '\n' + msg);
 
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Mass (kg):
          <input type="text" name="mass" value={this.state.mass} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Height (m):
          <input type="text" name="height" value={this.state.height} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  BMI_div / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So for more info on what I changed, add a name field to each of your inputs that is the same as the state value they correspond to.  And then change your `handleChange` function to set the state value corresponding to the input field who's value changed.